# ProxySQL giving me the error Access denied for user

Tags: mariadb, proxysql

I installed ProxySQL in my server.

Server details :
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

ProxySQL version : proxysql-2.0.2-1-centos7.x86_64.rpm
MaridaDB version : Distrib 10.3.7-MariaDB

Everything is working fine, but i am getting the following problem randomly.

```
 MySQL_Session.cpp:3966:handler___status_CONNECTING_CLIENT___STATE_SERVER_HANDSHAKE(): [ERROR] ProxySQL Error: Access denied for user 'user'@'*.*.*.*' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Is the error always for the same user and IP adress/host?

Comment: No it's Random..

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Same connection credentials sometimes work and sometimes don't. The same connection string sometimes connects and sometimes does not.

mysql -ustnduser -pstnduser -h172.17.0.2 -P 6033 -e "select user(),current_user(),@@hostname"

When I run the above commands it connects sometimes and sometimes not. mostly it connects.

Please help resolve this issue.

Comment: @Anup_Tripathi, I am sorry. I actually forgot how I solved this. I should have written the solution at the time , I solved it.

Comment: @FaizAhmed, please try to recall and add the solution in a comment or as a reply to the question.

Comment: There's a general explanation and pointers to possible issue with a specific usecarse for this issue I read in this blog of proxysql connectivity issues -> https://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/can-not-connect-to-proxysql-reasons-and-fixtures

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and searched on the internet but could not get any workable solution. Then I downgraded the ProxySql from version 2.4.x to 2.2.x and it worked. It is now working perfectly fine. I tested it with sysbench too. Not a single connection loss (or Access denied error) was observed.

Comment: I think, I did the same :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create the same user in the underlying database server as well and from the application, you are connecting to proxy sql server on port 6033. Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: created same user in MariaDB side

Answer (score 0):

Timezone difference with the connected server and the user can also be a reason for such ProxySQL errors, try setting the correct timezone.

PHP example:

```
date_default_timezone_set(“YOUR_TIME_ZONE”);
```

I was facing a similar problem and this helped me.